# Notification with workManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I'm creating application using PeriodicWorkRequest to execute or fire notification with content changing every day.
it work smoothly but i want to  test the content of next day, i search in this case but does not arrive to the best solution. i try to change the day in device but it still does not work

```
 val notificationWorkBuilderRepeated = PeriodicWorkRequest
            .Builder(Notification::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(notificationWorkBuilderRepeated)
```

Comment: If you only want to test the behaviour, the best approach is to make the interval customizable based on flavors. i.e. create a `dev` flavor and for that flavor, make the notification interval something like e.g. 5 minutes, If the notification appears on `dev` after 5 minutes, then it should appear on `production` after a day.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to write some androidTest using the [`WorkManagerTestInitHelper`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing).

This helper makes available a custom driver that you can use to test PeriodicWorkers simulating that the periodic delay has been met:

```
val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver()

// Tells the testing framework the period delay is met
testDriver.setPeriodDelayMet(request.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have worked for first time with **Work Manager** I also got this problem for testing.

I have just decreased interval for 15 minutes and tested.

Currently its working fine for every hour.

You can also test it by giving 15 minutes (minimum interval) to test it.

Hope it will helps you. Thank you.